# Trying to resize my UIView containers to fit smaller iPhone screen sizes

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

I am trying to have my layout fit on multiple iPhone screen sizes, but I am having trouble resizing my UIView's to resize themselves when on screen sizes smaller than the iPhone xr.

I have constrained the views, labels, and buttons properly and everything is aligned, but when viewing the app on smaller screen size, I don't fully understand how to resize my UIView containers to resize themselves to fit smaller screens.

On smaller screens, my button does not show up because the screen size is too small.  The UIView's are the issue and the stack views inside them also need to resize or shrink the text to fit everything on the screen.

Image of my storyboard, and respective screen sizes

[image]

Comment: Start designing from smallest screen and build UI up

Answer (score 0):

*"I don't fully understand how to resize my UIView containers to resize themselves to fit smaller screens."* -UIViews won't resize according to the screen, you will have to add constraint for them so that they pick their width and height. Alternatively you have to set constraint for fixed height and width.

In my opinion, for supporting smaller screen size, you must use scrollviews as parentview. So that user can scroll in the app. Also you can give relative width and height for views inside scrollview. 
Scrollviews are required because you will always want some minimum width and height for buttons, labels etc. Otherwise on larger screen like Ipad they will be very large, while on smaller screens they will be very small.

You can use TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView: [How to use TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625451/how-to-use-tpkeyboardavoiding-in-swift-project), or just google for that. It handles keyboard showing and hiding task, which is a headache otherwise.

Here is how I think you can solve your issue:
Set Some minimum height and width for your topmost view(scrollview preferably).
Now add other views inside it and use relative width and height. In relative width and height you give values in ratios. Here you can get an idea how to do that: -[Giving width in % values in autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373598/how-to-create-percentage-of-total-width-using-autolayout).
 Also add additional constraint on your internal views for minimum height and width so they don't fall below certain size.

I would not suggest, but you may always use `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width` and `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height` to get the width and height of screen. And according set values for your constraints in your view/controller class. Here is a link for setting value of constraint in swift class:
[set contraint value programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669554/how-to-update-the-constant-height-constraint-of-a-uiview-programmatically)

Comment: awesome! thanks for the links, I'll try to check out doing it programmatically as it seems more simple

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need any help.